# unwanted discrepancy between solid viewport and rendered viewport

Tags: uv, 3d-view, transparency, shader-nodes

I have a Digital Elevation Model (DEM) that I imported into blender and overlaid ontop of google geodata using the Blender GIS add on.  The DEM layer (shown in white in the 3D viewport) looks correct in solid viewport shading:
[image]

But when I switch to rendered viewport shading, a black color shows up near the middle of the DEM where it is supposed to be transparent:
[image]

Does anyone know why the black color shows up in rendered view?  How do I emit the black color so that it is transparent instead of black?  Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem is to connect *Alpha* sockets from .tif to *BSDF*, then go into *Material Properties* tab under *Settings > Blend mode > Alpha Clip*.